# Solving nonlinear system of n equation, n unknowns using GPU

Tags: matlab, gpu, symbolic-math, equation-solving, nonlinear-functions

Is this possible to solve a nonlinear system of n equation, n unknowns on Matlab, using graphical processor?

I can't think of any parallel solution for such an application, and `solve` function seems not implemented for GPU arrays in Matlab.

**Update**

Example:

```
syms x y z;
f1= x+y+z;
f2= x^2+y^2+z^2;
f3= x+y+z;
system=[f1;f2;f3];
solve(system)
vpasolve(system)
```

Comment: There might be something in Jacket (AccelerEyes, now ArrayFire)

Comment: @MarcoA. It's not free...

Comment: exactly which `solve` function are you talking about? Please post an example code using regular CPU functions.

Comment: @Amro See the update. I know only `solve` and `vpasolve` functions.

Comment: ah those are symbolic math functions! To answer you question, there is NO equivalent that runs of the GPU... But why do you want to do that in the first place?? It's not gonna run any faster, there is no numeric data involved..

Comment: @Amro Because it's too slow on CPU.

Comment: GPGPU is not a magic solution to make everything run faster! This sort of symbolic math manipulation is not gonna benefit from the GPU..

Comment: you can make the solver faster by adding explicit assumptions on the variables involved in the equations. So if you know that x/y/z are real you should let the solver know, similarly if you expect the solution to be in a specific range: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/assume.html

Comment: @Amro Yeah I know. As I said in question, I have no idea about how can a numerical method could be parallelized (or couldn't).